# A new array doesn't get generated when 'resize' event fires out

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate a new array each the the width of the browser changes. With this purpose, I keep an eye on the width with "resize" event. This event fires out every time the width changes. Hovewer, the new array doesn't get generated every time. Instead a same array is generated all the time.  [A link to my pen](https://codepen.io/JulieJones/pen/ExjxzJE)

```
 var shelfImages = document.querySelector(".shelf-images");
 var wrap = document.querySelector(".wrap");
 var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
 var arr = [ "1.jpg", "2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg"];

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
       getNumberOfShelves(arr, width);
    });
   window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
      getNumberOfShelves(arr, width);
    });

  function getNumberOfShelves(arra, w) {

    if (w >= 1126) {
      while (wrap.firstChild) {
      wrap.removeChild(wrap.firstChild);
    }
    var numberOfBooks = 4;
    var arrayOfArrays = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < arra.length; i += numberOfBooks) {
         arrayOfArrays.push(arra.slice(i, i + numberOfBooks));
    }  
} else if (w <= 1125 && w >= 583) {
    while (wrap.firstChild) {
       wrap.removeChild(wrap.firstChild);   
}
 var numberOfBooks = 3;
 var arrayOfArrays = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < arra.length; i += numberOfBooks) {
  arrayOfArrays.push(arra.slice(i, i + numberOfBooks));
 }
} else {
while (wrap.firstChild) {
  wrap.removeChild(wrap.firstChild);
}
  var numberOfBooks = 2;
  var arrayOfArrays = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < arra.length; i += numberOfBooks) {
      arrayOfArrays.push(arra.slice(i, i + numberOfBooks));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `width` you are passing to `getNumberOfShelves()` as  `w` is static. Try changing it to `getNumberOfShelves(arr, document.documentElement.clientWidth);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your `width` in the listener. As of now, `width` takes on initial value of `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and never changes. Try logging it in your resize listener to see what I mean.